# When is the N (negative) flag set in assembly?

Tags: assembly

Say we have the addition of the following two registers:

```
R0 = 6DEE 8765
R1 = 3458 FFDD
R0 + R1 = A2478742
```

Assuming we are using a 2's complement sign convention, what flags would be set? I know that overthrow would be set, but would "N" as well?

Regards

Comment: `N` flag is just the sign bit, which is the most significant one. So yeah, it would be set. The manual for your architecture (which you forgot to specify...) surely tells you this though. Also, you can just run it in a debugger.

Comment: So when an `N` and a `V` are both set, then that denotes the actual number is positive?

Comment: Yes it does. The overflow wrapped around.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot! I'd best answer you if I could...

Comment: Although all the processors I know of use N and V this way (the ones that actually have flags), you didnt specify an architecture so need to do that to complete the question so there is a single answer, and not close this for being too broad.  (some popular architectures dont have flags at all for good reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all architectures that support flags, the `N` or `Negative` flag simply matches the most significant bit of the last number computed.
In addition many architectures have a `O` or `Overflow` flag which tells you if the most significant bit was **changed** by the last operation.

If a register went from positive to negative both `O` and `N` will be set.
If the value in the register was negative before and after `N` will be set, but not `O`. etc.

The overflow flag is only useful when using signed arithmetic. When using unsigned arithmetic you use the `C` (`Carry`) flag, which tells you when the result exceeded the largest result the register can hold (0xFFFF FFFF in 32-bit).

Finally there is the `Z` `zero` flag which tells you if the result is zero or not.

Comment: That's not an accurate description of an overflow flag.  `neg eax` changing `-1` to `+1` is not signed overflow, but does flip the MSB.  `(-4) + 7` giving `+3` also doesn't set OF.  It's actually set when the MSB doesn't match the MSB of the mathematical full result, without truncating to the register width. 
 See http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt for details on how it's computed for addition, like XOR of carry-in and carry-out of the sign bit.

Comment: Also, many ISAs do call it `V` if they use a single letter, like the querent used in comments under the question.  (e.g. ARM does this, I think maybe AVR as well).  x86 calls it `OF`.  I hope there aren't any that just call it `O`, because of ambiguity with `0` in some fonts.

Comment: @Lerbi: Most likely the downvote on the question was for not specifying an architecture, as old_timer commented.  Like Johan, I think all ISAs with a Negative or Sign flag set it according to the MSB of the results.  But all asm questions should specify what architecture they're about (with tags), or which ones they're comparing.